# Add Images To String/Array Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am still learning java so just have a question. I have tabs and in each tab I have string-arrays showing the text data. At the moment, I have something like this, `showing different star names in a list view` but now I want to show the star name and a `little image` right next to it.

How can I achieve this?

```
public class CelebActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.celeb_layout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String [] tabs;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);

        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        {
            return tabs[position];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAB_POSITION_KEY = "TAB_PORITION_KEY";
    private ListView mainListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;


    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TAB_POSITION_KEY, position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);


        Bundle bundel = getArguments();

        int position = bundel.getInt(TAB_POSITION_KEY);

        ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

        mainListView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:


                String[] planets = new String[]{"Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                        "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
//                ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
                collection.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));
                break;

            case 1:
                String[] stars = new String[]{"Eridanus", "Cassiopeia", "Scorpius", "Crux",
                        "Cancer", "Leo", "Canis Major", "Taurus"};
//                ArrayList<String> starsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                collection.addAll(Arrays.asList(stars));
                break;

            case 2:
                String[] solarSystem = new String[]{"Inner Solar System", "Outer Solar System", "Trans-Neptunian region", "Farthest regions"};
//                ArrayList<String> solarSystemList = new ArrayList<String>();
                collection.addAll(Arrays.asList(solarSystem));
                break;
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simplerow, collection);
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return layout;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class as below:

```
class Star{
String starname;
String starimageurl;
}
```

then create an arraylist of it and add required data to it.

```
ArrayList<Star> starlist=new ArrayList<starlist>();
```

pass this into your adapter.